# $(1 - i)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ solution

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Can someone tell me a solution to $(1 - i)^{\frac{1}{4}}$? Not my homework, actually it's a friend of mine's, but now I'm interested in this whole thing.

(I would appreciate an explanation also, not just some random numbers :D)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know De Moivre's theorem?

Comment: Let's say, I heard of it, but I'm not an expert in math. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [De Moivre's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), which says that the $n$th roots of $r(\cos x + i \sin x)$ are $$r^{\frac{1}{n}} ( \cos \frac{x+2\pi k}{n} + i \sin \frac{x+2\pi k}{n})$$ where $k$ can be any positive integer from $0$ to $n-1$.

Firstly, we convert $1-i$ into polar form. The number's magnitude is $\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}$ or $\sqrt{2}$, and its angle is $315º$. This number has $r = \sqrt{2}, x = 315º, n = 4$ (we are finding the $4$th root), so substituting in this, we have:

$$\sqrt{2}^{\frac{1}{4}} ( \cos \frac{315º+2\pi k}{4} + i \sin \frac{315º+2\pi k}{4})$$

When $k=0$, $2^{\frac{1}{8}} ( \cos \frac{315º}{4} + i \sin \frac{315º}{4}) \approx 0.212 + 1.070i$.

When $k=1$, $2^{\frac{1}{8}} ( \cos \frac{45º}{4} + i \sin \frac{45º}{4}) \approx -1.070 + 0.212i$.

When $k=2$, $2^{\frac{1}{8}} ( \cos \frac{135º}{4} + i \sin \frac{135º}{4}) \approx -0.212 + 1.070i$.

Can you find the last root? There should be an obvious pattern, since you are rotating by exactly $90º$ each time.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe -1.070 + 0.212i ?

Comment: That's the case when $k=1$. Try again (notice that the roots go anticlockwise in a titled square). Since when $k=2$, the root is below the origin, when $k=3$, the root should be to the right of the origin.

Comment: Sooo... 1.070 - 0.212i?  Can't get it, seriously.

Comment: Yea, now I get it. It'll be 1.070 - 0.212i, finally I understand it. Thanks man, wish u were my math teacher back when I was a student. :D

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-i)^\frac{1}{4} = (\sqrt{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})^{\frac{1}{4}} =2^{\frac{1}{8}}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{16}} = \sqrt[8]{2}(\cos \frac{\pi}{16}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{16})$$

PS: Thanks to Wolfram, I came up with some unknown to me expression of $\cos \frac{\pi}{16} $ :

$$ \cos \frac{\pi}{16} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$

and

$$ \sin \frac{\pi}{16} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$

Comment: Of course. How uncareful of me. But, for my defense, OP asked for <<one solution>> :)

Answer (score 1):

I will use the standard interpretation of complex numbers as points / vectors in the plane. In this interpretation, addition of complex numbers corresponds to addition of vectors, multiplication of two complex numbers corresponds to multiplying their lengths and adding the angles they make to the positive $x$-axis, and lengths correspond to the standard Pythagorean theorem lengths of the plane.

Thus, a number raised to the fourth power means that its length is raised to its fourth power, and its angle is quadrupled. We want to find complex numbers so that the result of applying this operation is $1-i$, which has length $\sqrt2$ and angle $-\pi/4 ({}= -45^\circ)$.

If the length is raised to its fourth power to get the length of $\sqrt 2$, then the original length must've been $\sqrt[8]2$. Simple as that.

The angle, however is more interesting. We want an angle so that if you quadruple it, you get $-\pi/4$. That seems simple enough, it's just $-\pi/16$. However, there are other solutions as well.

Remember when I said that the angle of the number $1-i$ is $-\pi/4$? Well, I might just as well have said $7\pi/4$. If we go with that angle, then the original angle must've been $7\pi/16$, which is not the same as $-\pi/16$. But that's not all: I could just as well have said that the angle of $1-i$ is $15\pi/4$ or $-9\pi/4$. Either of these give different results for the original angle as well: $15\pi/16$ and $-9\pi/16$ respectively. However, you will be glad to know that these are all the answers. There are infinitely many possible angles I could say that $1-i$ has, but no matter which one I choose, the resulting original angle will be equivalent to one of the four we've found.

Thus we've found the four answers:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}&\text{length}&\text{angle}\\
\hline \text{Solution 1} &\sqrt[8]2 & -\frac\pi{16}\\
\text{Solution 2} &\sqrt[8]2 & \frac{7\pi}{16}\\
\text{Solution 3} &\sqrt[8]2 & \frac{15\pi}{16}\\
\text{Solution 4} &\sqrt[8]2 & -\frac{9\pi}{16}\\
\end{array}
$$
If you want to write them in rectangular form (i.e. as $a + bi$ for real numbers $a$ and $b$, like you've done with $1-i$), then a little trigonometry is needed. The first solution, for instance, may be written as
$$
\sqrt[8]2\cos(-\pi/16) + \sqrt[8]2\sin(-\pi/16)i \approx 1.0696 - 0.2127i
$$
The other three may be calculated similarily, changing which angle you insert into $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Let $$(1-i)^{1/4}=x+iy \implies 1-i=(x+iy)^4$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: And from where did the x + iy come from? :/

Comment: @Hienz Any complex number can be written in the form of $x+iy$, even if it's purely real, in that case $y=0$.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Kinda got it. :D

Comment: You get $1 - i = \big(x^4 - 6x^2y^2 + y^4\big) + 4i\,\big(x^3y-xy^3\big)$. Not exactly helpful.